# If two people play tic tac toe choosing their moves randomly, what are the odds that they will tie?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

What is the probability that it is a tie game?
What is the probability that X wins?
What is the probability that O wins?

Assume X goes first and all moves are random.

Answer (score 5):

In 2001 I worked out [the possible number of games](http://www.se16.info/hgb/tictactoe.htm)

```
Win in 5 moves    1440
Win in 6 moves    5328
Win in 7 moves   47952
Win in 8 moves   72576
Win in 9 moves   81792
Draw             46080
Total           255168
```

but these are not equally likely; you need to weight the wins in $5$ moves by $4!$, the wins in $6$ moves by $3!$, and so on.  If you do that then

- the probability for the first player wining at random is $\frac{1440\times 4!+47952\times2!+81792\times0!}{9!}\approx 0.585$
- the probability for the second player wining at random is $\frac{5328\times3!+72576\times1!}{9!}\approx 0.288$
- the probability of a draw is $\frac{46080\times0!}{9!}\approx 0.127$

Answer (score 3):

**Tie:** Since all final outcomes (with 5 Xs and 4 Os) are equally likely, we can count the number of outcomes which end in a tie.

- With an X in the center

  - X must appear in 1 of each pair: (NW, SE), (NE, SW), (N, S), (E, W), giving $2^4 = 16$ options
  - However, not all of these are  ties. There cannot be 3 Xs in a row, which can happen in one of $4$ different rows, and there will then be $2$ choices for placement of the last X, giving $8$ disallowed possibilities
  - So there are $16 -8 = 8$ possibilities with an X in the center
- With an O in the center

  - X in four corners and one edge: never a tie
  - X in three corners and two edges: determined by the omitted corner, $4$ possibilities
  - X in two corners and three edges: one choice given omitted edge, $4$ possibilities
  - X in one corner and four edges: never a tie
  - Total of $8$

So there are $16$ total final positions with ties, out of $\binom{9}{5}$ final positions

Comment: I think there are $16$ rather than $24$ drawn final positions: three basic patterns (one with the first player eventually in the centre and two with the second player eventually in the centre) which become $8+4+4$ after rotations and reflections

Comment: @Peter doesn't matter since we're computing probability

Comment: Your *"X in one corner and four edges"* will lead to a diagonal of Os.  So too might some of your *"X in two corners and three edges"*

Comment: @Henry You're right. That's what I get for writing too hastily.

Comment: Your revised $16/{9 \choose 5}$ is now the same as my $\frac{46080\times0!}{9!}$

Comment: @Peter Not all games are equally likely. A 5-move sequence has a higher probability than a 9-move sequence. Pretending the game finishes to 9 moves is equivalent to the weighting in Henry's answer.

Comment: @Y.Forman Yes, after having thought about it a while I noticed that.